# Return an opaque type of array

Tags: arrays, swift, opaque-result-type

Is it possible to return `some [T]` ?

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype X
    func method() -> [X]
}

class Imp: P {
    typealias X = Int

    func method() -> some [Int] {
        return [1]
    }
}
```

Code above produces error "An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class"

EDIT:
[image: Diagram]
So protocol hides underlying `@NSMangedObject` and expose only needed properties. It would be nice if A, B have `Comparable` capabilities.

Comment: If you give an actual basic example if a use case, then it could be possible to tell if this is a job for generics.

Comment: I've updated question with use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, but that's because it doesn't mean anything. `some T` means "a specific, concrete type that conforms to T, known by the returning function at compile time, but not known by the caller." `[Int]` is a type known to the caller. There is nothing "opaque" about it. This is identical to:

```
func method() -> [Int] { ... }
```

Comment: Hm, it makes sense.